# bash: what is the difference between redirecting stdin in the condition of a code block or at its end?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Is there any difference between adding the redirection in the code block statement instead of adding it in the end of it?

For example, what is the difference between:

```
if cat <<< foo; then
    code ...
fi
```

and:

```
if cat; then
    code ...
fi <<< foo
```

?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
if cat; then
    code ...
fi <<< foo
```

...stdin is modified *for the entire block*. Thus, `code ...` runs with stdin connected to the pipeline from the heresting, and can't read from the script's original stdin.

Whereas here:

```
if cat <<< foo; then
    code ...
fi
```

...the redirection is scoped to the one cat command, and your `code ...` runs with stdin connected to its original source.

---

Also of note is that if your block were a loop, `while cat <<< foo; do code ...; done` would read a new heredoc containing exactly `foo` on every iteration, whereas `while cat; do code ...; done <<<foo` is reading from a single heredoc throughout as many iterations as may take place (meaning, in this particular example, that all but the first will find the input source exhausted). Consider [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for some examples where this distinction is important.